# Nifi store Azure Blob account_name/account_key in a single place

Tags: apache-nifi

I have [DeleteAzureBlobStorage](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-azure-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.azure.storage.DeleteAzureBlobStorage/) and [PutAzureBlobStorage](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-azure-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.azure.storage.PutAzureBlobStorage/) in multiple places. From ducumentation those processors support "Storage Account Name" & "Storage Account Key" to be specified either in attributes or value registry. AFAIK, both ways are unsecure, the true way for sensitive information is to use Parameter Context.

So I ended up by copy-pasting name-key pair accross multiple processors. Very cumbersome taking into account I have 3 environments.

*Is there a better way to share DeleteAzureBlobStorage/PutAzureBlobStorage configs accross multiple processors?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those processors each have a property for [`AzureStorageCredentialsControllerService`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-azure-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.services.azure.storage.AzureStorageCredentialsControllerService/index.html) which is a controller service where Azure credentials are provided. Define the controller service and populate it once, and then reference it from as many processors as you like.

If you have multiple sets of credentials, you can also use the [`AzureStorageCredentialsControllerServiceLookup`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-azure-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.services.azure.storage.AzureStorageCredentialsControllerServiceLookup/index.html), which satisfies the requirements of the controller service above but actually serves as a resolver for multiple via the `azure.storage.credentials.name` attribute. For example, you could set up a *dev* and *test* with different credentials, provide a `ASCCS` for each pair of credentials, and register them both with the service lookup identified by `dev` or `test` respectively. Then when the flowfile coming through the processor has the `azure.storage.credentials.name` attribute value `dev`, those credentials would be used, and when `test`, the test credentials.

Comment: thank you! Shame on me I haven't looked there before asking)